# Why Js doesnt call the function?

Tags: javascript

So I have this function called redireccionar()

```
function redireccionar(){
            alert("activaste la funcion");
        }
```

[gyazo](http://gyazo.com/c86b48f3f96137bba0e32e1ae72c0daf)

and redireccionar() gets called by this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="redireccionar()" type="button">Go!</button>
```

[gyazo](http://gyazo.com/05bedfb6833a7e4e5e6b93b73ae4e1d2)

But I do click and nothing happens, its because I render them? How can I fix it? Why it doesnt work? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `its because I render them`???

Comment: You have somehow mixed your own Javascript with that of including jQuery (first screenshot), put it in its own `<script>`

Comment: Perhaps you have other JavaScript errors interfering with the execution of the function. Have you debugged your code or examined the browser's console for errors?

Answer (score 4):

You need to make a separate `<script>` tag for your custom JS, your first screenshot (http://gyazo.com/c86b48f3f96137bba0e32e1ae72c0daf) shows you have a script tag pulling in bootstrap and within that tag you are specifying your code.

Example solution:

```
<script src='/path/to/bootstrap/cdn'></script>
<script>
function redireccionar(){
    alert("activaste la funcion");
}
</script>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-src

Comment: I wasn't aware self-closing script tags even worked; what spec are you operating under?

Comment: still not working, as i said, it may be cause i render them? :  http://gyazo.com/4eae72e08ef33415c38f904c01a9c915

Comment: @RubenSaez I'm not familiar with that syntax, what framework are you using that uses that $:render syntax? Make sure that the final output HTML file contains the scripts you are expecting.

Comment: @DavidHughes Everything I'm reading is suggesting your answer is wrong from the fact that the script tag does not self-close; enlighten me as to this?  I still have yet to vote on your answer.

Comment: @Daedalus Apologies that was a typo, the tag isn't self closing - rectified this in my answer. The point I was illustrating however was that you should not have code inside a script tag if you are wanting to use the src attribute to load external scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Oh! I just checked your picture and found something like this:

```
<script src="......bootstrap.min.js">
//your code here
</script>
```

---

You shouldn't include your script within that bootstrap framework. Do like this:

```
<script src="path-of-boostrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
//your code here
</script>
```

Comment: Hi m8, can you help me with one little thing?

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola Ruben! Your first screenshot shows the problem. Your function has to be surrounded by separate `<script></script>` tags, not inside of the linked bootstrap js file. Everything else should be fine so far.

Comment: 1+ for Bhojendra from me, for the faster and better explained answer :-)

Comment: Hi ddlab, can you help me with 1 little thing? Im new here and i dont know how this works, i dont know how to send a PM if it's possible

Comment: con placer :-) how can I help you ?